# Collect UDP packets lost during iPerf test

Tags: snmp, networking, udp, throughput, iperf

I'm testing my network infrastructure where I'm using **iPerf** and *UDP* protocol.

I'm using the following:

On the server side:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-0-1-11:~$ iperf -s -u
```

and the client side:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-2-1-10:~$iperf -c 172.0.1.11 -u -b 100m
```

I understand that when more traffic than a link can handle is sent to a link, the interface to that link will end up dropping the packets destined for that link. However, I'm interested in collecting those packet loss rates. Is there a way to collect it?

I'm running *Cacti* an open-source, web-based network monitoring and graphing. **SNMP** server is enabled in the Cisco routers.

```
Router(config)#snmp-server community public RO 
Router(config)#snmp-server community private RW
```

I'm getting the collected data of the interfaces in the Cacti server. However, I want also to have packet loss data collected, too.

**Edited part of the question**

I added the *In/Out Errors/Discarded Packets* to the graphs' tree in **Cacti**. However, so far there is no data which is collected, it is always **0**, and I can see from **Iperf** that there is *packets loss*, although there are data and graphs for the *In/Out Bits* graphs.

This the information I got from the interface:

```
{
"Cisco-IOS-XE-interfaces-oper:statistics": {
    "discontinuity-time": "2019-06-26T15:09:55.000005+00:00",
    "in-octets": "4140080366",
    "in-unicast-pkts": "5381499",
    "in-broadcast-pkts": "0",
    "in-multicast-pkts": "0",
    "in-discards": 0,
    "in-errors": 0,
    "in-unknown-protos": 0,
    "out-octets": 2579777476,
    "out-unicast-pkts": "13916798",
    "out-broadcast-pkts": "0",
    "out-multicast-pkts": "0",
    "out-discards": "2843",
    "out-errors": "0",
    "rx-pps": "5527",
    "rx-kbps": "34266",
    "tx-pps": "16523",
    "tx-kbps": "106588",
    "num-flaps": "0",
    "in-crc-errors": "0"
}
```

}

Apparently, there's no packet loss recorded in `in-errors` and `out-errors` which are both **0**. However, sometimes I got packet loss from the **Iperf** report:

```
[  5] local 172.2.1.10 port 5001 connected with 172.0.1.11 port 43372
[  5]  0.0-842.3 sec  23.8 MBytes   237 Kbits/sec   0.250 ms    2/17008 (0.012%)
[  4] local 172.2.1.10 port 5001 connected with 172.0.1.11 port 43961
[  4]  0.0-857.3 sec  23.8 MBytes   233 Kbits/sec   0.548 ms    9/17008 (0.053%)
[  5] local 172.2.1.10 port 5001 connected with 172.0.1.11 port 51505
[  5]  0.0-872.4 sec  23.8 MBytes   229 Kbits/sec   0.260 ms    0/17008 (0%)
```

I really don't understand the reason for this packet loss.

P.S. in my network infrastructure, I'm running *Segment Routing* where I have 4 routers where the traffic flow might pass one router multiple times depends on the *Segment Routing Explicit Path*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your Cacti version, we collect errors and discarded packets without any problems on Version 1.1.38.

Here's how we do it.

Select the tab Console, then extend Management and click devices.

[image]

In the device list, select the switch/router you want to get the information from.

[image]

Now under the selected device, click create graph for the device.

[image]

Now at bottom select the In/Out Errors/Discarded Packets in the roll-down menu, then select the interface, where you want to create the counter on. The click create.

[image]

That's basically how you do it. I assume you have added the device correctly to Cacti and setup SNMP correctly. Otherwise this wont work.

Please note that Cacti takes a bit of time before generating the graph. Several tests should give you data within a short time.

Comment: thanks! I added the _In/Out Errors/Discarded Packets_ to the graphs' tree. However, so far there is no data which is collected, it is always 0, and I can see from **Iperf** that there is packets loss, although there are data and graphs for the _In/Out Bits_ graphs. Is there any configuration must be done on the routers to catch _Errors/Discarded Packets_ ?

Comment: @KhalilMebarkia, are you sure that there is congestion enough to drop packets? It may be that there is no packet loss.

Comment: @RonMaupin This one of Server report: `[  5]  0.0-1921.3 sec  47.6 MBytes   208 Kbits/sec   0.357 ms   81/34015 (0.24%)
[  3] local 172.2.1.10 port 5001 connected with 172.0.1.11 port 34450`  I think value **81** is the number of lost datagrams, and **34015** is the number of datagrams which are sent.  My links are set to _200Mbps_ bandwidth in the configuration and I sent _40Mpbs_ traffic in an infinite loop for _20mins_ using **Iperf**.

Comment: @KhalilMebarkia, you really need to eidt your question to include the router configuration. Also, clear the counters o the router, run your test, and give use the statistics directly from the router CLI, too. You need to compare what Cacti is telling you with what the router itself says to see if there really is a problem.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks, I will redo the test and edit my questions. One question please, the statistics from _CLI_ can be shown using this _CLI_: `show interfaces interface_name` and check the `input errors` and `output errors` fields, right?

Comment: @KhalilMebarkia use `show interface counters errors` to get all error counters. On Cisco routers drops are shown on the `show interface interface_name`

Comment: @KhalilMebarkia, it sounds like you may be dropping the traffic before it gets to the router. For example, on a switch that is oversubscribed, or in the source host that is trying to send more traffic than its interface can handle. Your destination may also be dropping packets. In any case, if the router isn't seeing drops, then it isn't happening on the router.

Comment: @RonMaupin That's totally true! I will try to plot the endpoint Linux-based Outbound traffic and watch the drop. Like you said if the router isn't seeing the drops, then it isn't happening on the router. However, if you look at `out-discards` which appeared in loss graph. What does that value mean?